# How can I deserialize JSON to a Dictionary<string,List<Object> in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am new, I have problem with deserialisation from JSON following data. I'm so thankful for helping me.

In documentation of API I have:

```
cabin_restrictions - (object or null) or Array of arrays
This object array provides the cabin restriction details for each cabin class under each applicable airline when fare families are available in the itinerary. 

One of object or nullArray of arrays
{airline_code}: {
  {cabin_class}: {
   bookingClass: string 
   cabinClass: string
   marketingAirline: string
   summaryText: string
   completeText: Array of strings
   detailsText: Array of strings
   upsellAvailabilityNotice: string
   altUpsellNotice: string
 }
}
```

For example in same documentation I have:

```
"cabin_restrictions": {
    "UA": {
        "BEC": {
            "bookingClass": "N",
            "cabinClass": "BEC",
            "marketingAirline": "UA",
            "summaryText": "This flight includes a Basic Economy fare. This fare does not allow carry-on bags or complimentary seat selection",
            "detailsText": [
                "You have selected a United Basic Economy fare. The following restrictions apply:\r",
                "Seat(s) will be assigned prior to boarding\r",    
                "Upgrades and Economy Plus® are not available post purchase"
            ],
            "completeText": [
                "Your flight includes a basic economy fare, United's most restrictive fare. The following restrictions apply: \r",
                "* No upgrades and limits on award miles: MileagePlus® members, including Premier® members, will not receive Premier® qualifying credit or lifetime miles; paid, earned, complimentary or mileage upgrades; or Economy Plus® seating benefits"
            ],
            "altUpsellNotice": "Basic Economy. This fare does not allow carry-on bags. Advance seat selection available for a fee."
        }
    }
},
```

I have this models for deserialisation but it doesn't work:

```
public class CabinRestrictions
    {

        [JsonPropertyName("cabin_restrictions")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<CabinClass>> airline_cabin_restrictions { get; set; }


        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, object> additionalProperties { get; set; }
      
    }

 public class CabinClass
    {
       
        public string bookingClass { get; set; }
        public string cabinClass { get; set; }
        public string marketingAirline { get; set; }
        public string summaryText { get; set; }
        public List<string> completeText { get; set; }
        public List<string> detailsText { get; set; }
        public string upsellAvailabilityNotice { get; set; }
        public string altUpsellNotice { get; set; }

    }
```

I am trying to deserialise with:

```
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
            cancellationToken);

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<GetAirFlightLookUpRoot>(stream, _options, cancellationToken);
```

// it's not all code..

I receive the response for the other values but for "cabin_restrictions" i couldn't.

Result in debug:

[image: image of results]

Comment: You are trying to deserialize to a `GetAirFlightLookUpRoot` but you haven’t shown that class? Also `completeText` should be a string array. Please edit your question so your problem can be reproduced - sample JSON, the whole class you are deserialising to, the deserialisation code, and the exact problem - you have most of that already, just a few bits missing!

Comment: Each json object van be made a dictionary of string object. But we're not programming javascript, we're doing C#. So serialize to static types/actual classes instead. You also seem to be missing the UA and BEC layers in your model.

Comment: @stuartd Hi, I edited completeText in string array, I didn't post the all code from GetAirFlightLookUpRoot because is too large, the other parts of  GetAirFlightLookUpRoot are deserialised correctly you can see it in img which I attached ,just cabin restriction deserialisation is problem here  I receive - null. May be I can't understand correctly the documentation from API. the response for test comes from mocked json data where I insert that for cabin restriction - I put it up in question ..after here "For example in same documentation I have:...".

Comment: @stuartd But from documentation I understand that {airline_code} and {cabin_class} may to be different values not just "UA" and "BEC" and I don't know what to paste in my model for deserialisation and how to mock it in json file

Comment: This looks it will need [custom deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to).

Comment: I recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json. Otherwise you will need an incredibly complecated code.

Answer (score -1):

to deserialize the json string you posted you need to fix your class, your property should be List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CabinClass>>>

```
var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<CabinRestrictions>(stream, _options, cancellationToken);

public class CabinRestrictions
{
    public JsonNode cabin_restrictions
    {
        private get { return null; }

        set
        {
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(JsonArray))
                airline_cabin_restrictions = value.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CabinClass>>>>();
            else
                airline_cabin_restrictions = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CabinClass>>> { value.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CabinClass>>>() };
        }
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CabinClass>>> airline_cabin_restrictions { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> additionalProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json. Otherwise you will need an incredibly complecated code to implement this

```
cabin_restrictions - (object or null) or Array of arrays
This object array provides the cabin restriction details for each cabin class under each applicable airline when fare families are available in the itinerary. 

One of object or nullArray of arrays
{airline_code}: {
```